# Indexing Properties on Neo4j

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I want to set indexes on properties for nodes in Neo4j but I got confused by the index approach of Neo4j. I have nodes for persons which are described by the properties id ( i don't want to use the internal ids (integer)), age (integer) and gender (String). Now i would like to set indexes for those three properties.

Could anyone describe me a solution approach. I am going to import my test data with the batch inserter from Micheal Hunger.

Answer (score 0):

[Here are the relevant documentation items](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-schema-index.html)

To create the indexes you want:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(myID)
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(age)
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(gender)
```

When you query against those properties, your indexes will be used.

Comment: thank you. i will try it. i didn´t know that is working with strings as well

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer if this is what you want.